# Facebook deprecated share feature... but it is using it itself?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

As we all know (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/) Facebook has deprecated the share function. However, the about to go live app center apparently is using the very same share UI.

[image: app center]

Is there a way for the regular folks to access the same UI from JS SDK provided by Facebook? Assuming, it is not the same as described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's deprecated, you can still use it in the way it was used before.
[Facebook Share Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/)

However, It's not a good idea to use this. Instead, you can just create a facebook app and use FB.ui to perform this action:

Example Code:

```
<script>
      FB.init({appId: "<your_app_id>", status: truey, cookie: true});

      function postToFeed() {

       FB.ui({
          method: 'feed',
          link: '<the_link>',
          name: '<name>',
          caption: '<caption>',
          description: '<description>'
        });

      }   

   </script>
```